# Share a sessionid between tomcat and nginx subdomain

Tags: java, session, tomcat, nginx, session-cookies

I am making a POST from localhost page (tomcat) to sub.localhost (nginx server which passes the request to tomcat). I need this POST call to have the same session id that localhost page does, because POST call authenticates.

I see that GET and POST requests to same domain have the same session id. Now when i post to a subdomain, it has a different one. How can i modify my configuration so that the session id remains the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass session id with **JSESSIONID** in the URL to your tomcat server, and tomcat will automatically use this sessionId:

```
http://www.some-URL.com;jsessionid=123456AFGT3
```